# coredump seen for string permutation codes

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, permutation

I'm trying to write some codes to check whether two strings are permutation of each other, but I saw error prompting there's coredump, I tried to printout the output but didn't get clue of what's wrong, codes are pretty simple, anybody have any clue? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


bool Permutation(string &A, string &B) {
    
    vector<int> a1(26);
    vector<int> b1(26);
    for (const char ch:A)
    {
        a1[ch-'a']++;
    }
    for (const char ch:B)
    {
        b1[ch-'b']++;
        
    }
  

    if(a1==b1)
   {
       return true;
    }else
   {
        return false;
   }
}
int main() {
  string a="abcd";
  string b="bcda";
  bool res=Permutation(a, b);
  if (res==true)
  {
   cout<<"permutation!"<<endl;
  }else
  {
  cout<<"not permutation!"<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

error seen:

=================================================================
==16==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60b0000000ec at pc 0x561be10aed68 bp 0x7ffcbc608970 sp 0x7ffcbc608960
READ of size 4 at 0x60b0000000ec thread T0
#0 0x561be10aed67 in Permutation(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >&) /home/coderpad/solution.cpp:16
#1 0x561be10af0f8 in main /home/coderpad/solution.cpp:31
#2 0x7f7785647b96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
#3 0x561be0fa2e09 in _start (/home/coderpad/solution+0x8e09)

0x60b0000000ec is located 4 bytes to the left of 104-byte region [0x60b0000000f0,0x60b000000158)
allocated by thread T0 here:
#0 0x561be1071220 in operator new(unsigned long) (/home/coderpad/solution+0xd7220)
#1 0x561be10b179c in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) /usr/include/c++/8/ext/new_allocator.h:111
#2 0x561be10b15ae in std::allocator_traitsstd::allocator<int >::allocate(std::allocator&, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/8/bits/alloc_traits.h:436
#3 0x561be10b128d in std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:296
#4 0x561be10b0b46 in std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator >::_M_create_storage(unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:311
#5 0x561be10aff2e in std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator >::_Vector_base(unsigned long, std::allocator const&) /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:260
#6 0x561be10af703 in std::vector<int, std::allocator >::vector(unsigned long, std::allocator const&) /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:416
#7 0x561be10aea27 in Permutation(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >&) /home/coderpad/solution.cpp:9
#8 0x561be10af0f8 in main /home/coderpad/solution.cpp:31
#9 0x7f7785647b96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow /home/coderpad/solution.cpp:16 in Permutation(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >&)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
0x0c167fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0c167fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0c167fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0c167fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0c167fff8000: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c167fff8010: 00 00 00 00 00 fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa[fa]00 00
0x0c167fff8020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c167fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c167fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c167fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c167fff8060: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
==16==ABORTING
/usr/local/bin/startshell: line 49:    16 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./solution
Core dump detected, launch GDB? [Y/n]

Comment: What happened when you launched GDB and debugged it?

Comment: When `ch` is equal to `a`, `ch-'b'` computes to be -1, which is not a valid index into `b1`.

Comment: In case you're unaware, there is [`std::is_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation)

Comment: Thanks enhzflep, I didn't use GDB, just the leetcode compiler itself calls the GDB, thanks Jeremy, I think that's exactly the issue. Thanks Cigien, good to know. :) much easier to use STL.